# What is the fastest way for matrix multiplication in Python?

Tags: python, time, matrix-multiplication

I am writing an application in Python having speed as the main driver. While optimizing my code, I found out that the main bottleneck is given by the code used to compute

[image]

In my code, this matrix multiplication is computed as

```py
POW = np.arange(4)
y = C @ (x ** POW)
```

I tried to use different methods (e.g., `for` cycle and others), but as now this is the fastest way I found. Do you have any suggestion to improve the computational time?

Comment: by using `numpy` probably

Comment: That's very small, should take almost no time at all.

Comment: "writing an application in Python having speed as the main driver" – erm, just don't.

Comment: Yes, I am already using numpy (see the command `np.arange` in the code)

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely to use Numpy. Numpy does the actual mathematical operations in highly optimized C code. Using Numpy is faster than writing your own non-optimized C code.

Comment: I am already using numpy (see the command `np.arange` in the code)

Comment: And I’m saying that what you’re doing - using Numpy - is the fastest way. What you’re doing should be ~ 1000 ms.

Comment: 1 second for such a small computation?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been ~ 1000 *n*s. I.e. 1 microsecond.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use float instead int. Secondly, if you don't need double precision then use np.float32.

```
POW = np.arange(4, dtype='f')
# C = C.astype('f', copy=False) # ensure that C.dtype == np.float32
y = C @ (x ** POW)
```